# Node tcp socket: Read binary data from Enfora MT4000

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, type-conversion, binary-data

I'm working with an Enfora MT4000 device. The device sends data to tcp or udp server when certain event has occurred. Data can be send in binary or ASCII format, but I need to use binary.

Enfora device is configured with AT commands like this:

```
AT$EVENT=14,0,7,1,1
AT$EVENT=14,3,52,14,1578098
```

When I configure the device with ASCII, the server receives data in this format:

```
r        13    0    0 $GPRMC,211533.00,A,3321.856934,S,07040.240234,W,0.0,0.0,120514,2.3,W,A*2B
```

But, when I use binary, the data looks like this:

```
$2K�  �Dk����a�H
```

Anyone knows how Node.js can convert binary data from a socket? I'm trying to do this with a very simple script.

```
// server
require('net').createServer(function (socket) {
    console.log("connected");
    socket.setEncoding(null);
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
})

.listen(3041);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` argument in your 'data' event handler is already a [Buffer](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html). By calling `data.toString()` you are converting that Buffer to a (UTF-8 by default) string. You're probably better off keeping it as a Buffer and using that if you need the original binary data.

Comment: It is possible to convert the buffer's data to `string` with javascript?

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so the default buffer.toString() should return the correct results

Comment: @DaniloAburto It's not clear what kind of string you're expecting. If the data is part binary and part string, you can use data.[toString()](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) with both encoding and start and end arguments.

Comment: I was confused with the data type. I resolved the problem by reading buffer directly (00 24 00 05 02 00...). Thanks to @mscdex.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you give an example of reading binary from a Node.js Buffer object? Having trouble finding information on that.